# NodeJS - How to use the twitch API with OAuth and code token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, twitch, twitch-api

> Hey today i tried to use the twitch api to fetch user data with this endpoint
>   `GET https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users` i wanted to use the authentification feature to skip the api-limit.

---

I choose ExpressJs for the web framework

### Here is my app.js file (entry point)

```js
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express()

const twitchClientSecret = process.env.twitchAppToken || require('./creditentials.json').twitchAppToken
const twitchClientID = process.env.twitchClientId || require('./creditentials.json').twitchClientId

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.get('/twitch-oauth', (req, res) => {
        console.log("hey")
        const requestToken = req.query.code
        console.log("requesttoken:" + requestToken)
        // if (req.query.code) {
            axios({

                method: 'post',

                url: `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=${twitchClientID}&client_secret=${twitchClientSecret}&code=${requestToken}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=localhost:8080/twitch-oauth`,

                headers: {
                    accept: 'application/json'
                }
            }).then((response) => {

                console.log(response)
                console.log("response" + response)
                const accessToken = response.data.access_token
                res.cookie('twitch_id_token', accessToken)

                res.redirect('/')
            }).catch((error) => {
                // Error 
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                    console.log(error.response.status);
                    console.log(error.response.headers);
                } else if (error.request) {
                    console.log(error.request);
                } else {

                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                }
                console.log(error.config);
            });
        // }
    })
// Start the server on port 8080
app.listen(8080)
```

### Here is my index.html (file served with HTTP `__dirname + '/public'`)

```html
<a id="twitch-auth" href="https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=6mrxy6lqs4m9svcim8ssr44ypzvk1c&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/twitch-oauth&response_type=code&scope=user:read:email&state=">
        Login with Twitch
    </a>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#twitch-auth").href = document.querySelector("#twitch-auth").href + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    </script>
    <script src="logic.js"></script>
```

### And finally my logic.js file

```js
const token = Cookies.get('twitch_id_token')
var cookie = document.cookie;
console.log(token);
if (token) {
    fetch('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?id=44322889', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        }
    })
    // Parse the response as JSON
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    });
}
```

## The problem

When i click the button "Login with Twitch" i get an http error when axios POST this request : `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=${twitchClientID}&client_secret=${twitchClientSecret}&code=${requestToken}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=localhost:8080/twitch-oauth`

I returns `{status: 400, message: "Parameter redirect_uri does not match registered URI"}`

Can someone help me ? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

```
{status: 400, message: "Parameter redirect_uri does not match registered URI"}
```

The response is basically telling you : '**Bad Request**' because the parameter `redirect_uri` in your request.

`localhost:8080/twitch-oauth` **has not been registered as a valid redirection URI**.

You probably have to go to the OAuth section and set `localhost:8080/twitch-oauth` as a valid `redirect_uri`, so the Twitch platform will allow the redirection and treat the request correctly.

From the Twitch Dev Documentation :

> `redirect_uri`    : **URI** :
>   Your registered redirect URI. This must exactly match the redirect URI registered in the prior, [Registration](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/#registration) step.Your registered redirect URI. This must exactly

Hope this clears your problem.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but i tried to change the values on the twitch console but nothing change
[image](https://i.imgur.com/sSJcyZV.png)